# Integrating Microsoft Authenticator with Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have successfully integrated our web application to utilize Azure AD for authentication using a SAML2 component called SAML SSO from ComponentPro, but our application also provides for a user to sometimes submit their Username and Password (it's configurable) in order to check in a document or approve a revision. SAML has no provision for passing a username and password back to the IdP for "re-verification," so that's not an option.

What we'd like to do in this case is to integrate the Microsoft Authenticator tool so that when using Azure AD as the Authentication source, instead of prompting the user for their username and password, we prompt them for their Authenticator code that corresponds to their Business-created Azure Active Directory Account.

We've created the Microsoft Application, have the Application ID and the Application Secret Password, but searching everywhere, I can't find anything to finish this seemingly simple task.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated!

All The Best,

John

Comment: AFAIK, there is no option to integrate your web app with MS authenticator.

Comment: Thanks @WayneYang-MSFT - is there any other way query Azure Active Directory with an API or REST call with a username and password?

Comment: @JohnWaller FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-connectors

MFA (including the Authenticator app) and OTP-only authentication are available with Azure AD (Now even with the Azure AD free plan) and the link offers some more information on how to integrate with your application.